# How to check tag of view in which touch occurred

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am developing a `Xamarin.Forms` application targeting the iOS platform. I want to only allow stylus input (i.e. disallow finger/direct input) in my entire app **except** for one single control (a `SwitchCell`).

For that, I implemented a custom `UIApplication` class and overrode the `SendEvent(UIEvent uievent)` method.

In `SendEvent` I am checking whether the event is a touch event using `uievent.Type == UIEventType.Touches`. Then I want to detect, if the touch occurred in the `SwitchCell` in which touch input should be allowed.
Because the `SwitchCell` is created in my `Xamarin.Forms` project as XAML, I implemented my own `TaggableSwitchCell` class inheriting from `SwitchCell` with a `Tag` property and registered a `CustomRenderer` that sets the `Tag` property of the `UITableViewCell` on iOS (which works as expected):

```cs
public class TaggableSwitchCellRenderer : SwitchCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            cell.Tag = (item as TaggableSwitchCell).Tag;
            Log.Debug("Setting tag to " + cell.Tag);
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

Then, in the `SendEvent` method, I check for the tag:

```cs
 var isTouchAllowed = uievent.AllTouches.Any((touch) =>
            {
                var uitouch = touch as UITouch;
                return uitouch.View != null && uitouch.View.ViewWithTag(Constants.Tag) != null;
            });
```

Running this code on the device (iPad Pro 3rd Generation) works fine for every touch that is not in the `SwitchCell`. However, if the touch is in the `SwitchCell` (meaning `isTouchAllowed` should be `true`), the following message is printed (the app does not crash):

```
invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
```

I know, that the problem is with the `uitouch.View.ViewWithTag(Constants.Tag) != null` statement, but I don't know how to solve it. I already tried manually checking the view tag using `uitouch.View.Tag == Constants.Tag` but this leads to the same problem.

Comment: It seems a known issue with UISwitch , reported here : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/132035

Comment: @cole-xia-msft yes, that appears to be the underlying issue. What's interesting however, is that the switch works without any issues if I remove the `ViewWithTag` call in the `SendEvent` method. I guess I have no other choice but to wait for a fix from Apple.

Comment: yep , it looks like a bug in UIKit depends on latest response from apple side .